# Fit div size to background image

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-size

I'm trying to set the size (both width and height) of a div to match it's background image size, but I can't get it working.
The background image size has to be in percentages, because I'm dealing with a responsive website. On smaller screens, the background should be displayed completely (with less width, but still proportional), and the div who has the image should follow that size.

I tried various values of the background-size, such as auto 100%, cover, contain, etc. but nothing did the trick.
There's a similar question here about this: [scale div to background image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279959/scale-div-to-background-image-size) but it didn't solve my problem either.

I'd really appreciate if someone knows how to do it.

**EDIT:**
I made a fiddle to show the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/osv1v9re/5/
This line is what is making the background image so small:

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

But if it is removed is removed, the background will fill the proper width, but not the height.

Comment: We would like to solve your problem if you can give us the code you are trying

Comment: Make a fiddle so we can help you

Comment: `<div>` tag cannot adapt to `background-image` size, you need to use an `<img>` tag and choose between `height: auto` for the `div` or javascript

Comment: It's no possible unless you know the image' width and height at every breakpoint. Another way to do this is to set the background-image to cover on the div. Here's an example. http://codepen.io/pacMakaveli/pen/oXLPKd

Comment: @shadi1024 I made a fiddle and updated the question.

Comment: @Heah Unfortunately, I'm unable of changing the background-image for an <img> tag. That would solve the problem, I know...

Comment: @Vlad I need the background-image to display 100%, it can't be cropped.

Comment: Can't you have the `div` size in percentage and the `background-size` to `contain` ?

Comment: @Heah thanks! That totally solved it. If you put it as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<div>` tag cannot adapt to background-image size, you need to use an `<img>` tag and choose between height: auto for the div or javascript

```css
    /* **** Problem **** */

    /* Wrong html */
    <div class="my_class"><div>
    
    /* with css : */
    .my_class {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url(/images/my-image.jpg);
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    /* ****  Solution **** */

    /* use css: */
    .my_class {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url(/images/my-image.jpg);
        background-size: contain;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


div{
    width: 100%;
}
div figure{
    padding-top: 36.56%;  /* 702px/1920px = 0.3656 */
    display: block;
    background: url("https://st.fl.ru/images/landing/bg2.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;  
}
```

```html
<div>    
    <figure></figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can have a responsive height using the padding-bottom or padding-top
because you can't fix an height property in '%' with a width in '%'.

```css
div{

 background-image: url(url);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center;

 margin: 0 auto;

 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom:  heightPicure / widthPicture + %; //do it manually or using scss rules

}
```