# Dynamically change height of flexbox container object based on contents

Tags: css, flexbox

Fiddle:

https://codepen.io/0akd0adk0asdk09asd/pen/QWbaLZa

When the browser is resized, the images are being correctly resized, and the width of the container is changing correctly, but the height of the container is not changing. If I remove height: 375px; the box collapses. How do I make the height responsive like the width currently is?

Basically I need to dynamically set the height: to the automatic width * aspect ratio. The images are always the same size so it's not an issue to use a fixed aspect ratio. I would rather use CSS over javascript to do this if possible.

Alternatively if there is another way to do it based on the background-image that would work too.

This is not a duplicate of [Fit div size to background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319743/fit-div-size-to-background-image). Do not close this as a duplicate of that question. That question assumes a static background image size.

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">c</div>
    <div class="bc">g</div>

  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="t">
      <div class="tl"></div>
      <div class="tr">Servant</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mc">2</div>
    <div class="bc">3</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  min-height: 375px;
  padding: 0.1rem;
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.card {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/q8WyDB6.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin: 0.2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  max-width: 148px;
  max-height: 375px;

  min-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

.card::after {
  content: "";
}

.t {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.tl {
  min-height: 30px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}

.tr {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .1);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;

}

.mc {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .1);
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
}

.bc {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .1);
  padding: 1.0rem 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: You are still trying to size elements based on the background and that's not possible. You need to use actual inline images

Comment: You are saying it's impossible to have a dynamic height based on the width of another object times a constant? I would accept even a JS solution to this if CSS is impossible. Can CSS obtain the width of a child element for calculating the height?

Comment: I'm saying that the "object" is a **background image** which has no intrinsic height to affect anything. You can't size to a background...it's **styling** not a "child element".

Answer (score 0):

OK, I accomplished it using Javascript:

https://codepen.io/0akd0adk0asdk09asd/pen/QWbaLZa

A css-only approach would be good, but not sure this is possible.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    updateContainer();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        updateContainer();
    });
});

function updateContainer() {
    var containerWidth = $('.t').width() * (375/148);
        $('#container').css({
            height: containerWidth
        });
}
```